# Cakephp SMTP emails syntax error

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp, cakephp-1.3

I've got a problem with email sending in cake. My method looks like this:

```
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
            'port'=>'465', 
            'timeout'=>'30',
            'auth' => true,
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'username'=>'mymail@gmail.com',
            'password'=>'mypass',
        );

        $this->Email->from    = "admin@localhost";
        $this->Email->to      = "my_test_mail@centrum.cz";
        $this->Email->subject = "Test";
        $this->Email->sendAs = "text";

        $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';

        $this->Email->send('Hello message body!');
```

But when I try to send the email I get:

```
555 5.5.2 Syntax error. l3sm512374fan.0
```

What do I need to chnage in order for this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per [RFC2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-3.3), to which Google's SMTP servers seem to be a stickler on, the format of the email addresses should be in the following way:

```
Recipient Name <myname@example.com>
-or-
<myname@example.com>
```

Do this for both the `from` and `to` address, and you should be good to go. If you don't have the name of the user, then you can just repeat the email:

```
$this->Email->to = "my_test_mail@centrum.cz <my_test_mail@centrum.cz>";
-or-
$this->Email->to = "<my_test_mail@centrum.cz>";
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Same EXACT problem... Have there been any updates or any other reasons why this syntax error might occur?

Comment: You should really post some code to help us figure out where the problem might be. Also include the version of CakePHP you're using.

Comment: I still get the same msg: `MAIL FROM: Recipient Name <myname@example.com>`
`555 5.5.2 Syntax error. qh1si1152456pba.999`