# Meteor accounts failing with gmail while Email.send works, why?

Tags: gmail, meteor-accounts

We have a Meteor application that we're getting ready to deploy and we're finally at the point of hooking it up to a gmail account to send emails. The email configuration is setup as

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  smtp = {
  username: 'noreply@cloaklabs.com',
  password: 'abcdabcdabcdabcd', // masked - a gmail application-specific 16 character password to use for two-factor auth
  server:   'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587 // also tried 465 to no avail
  };
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
});
```

When the application calls Email.send(...) directly the email is sent successfully.

However when we do:

```
Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password, profile: profile},function(err){...})
```

We get the following traceback in the server log:

```
Exception while invoking method 'createUser' SenderError: Mail from command failed - 555 5.5.2 Syntax error. ba12sm12306756pac.23 - gsmtp
at Object.Future.wait (/Users/Michel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1wbeh3b++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:91:1)
at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:168:1)
at Object.Accounts.sendVerificationEmail (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:602:1)
at Meteor.methods.createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:723:1)
at tryLoginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:186:1)
at Object.Accounts._loginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:302:1)
at [object Object].Meteor.methods.createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:699:1)
... traceback truncated
```

This feels like a bug. About as close as I get to a relevant question on SO is [555 5.5.2 Syntax error. gmail's smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321346/555-5-5-2-syntax-error-gmails-smtp) There the recommendation is to use

```
"name <emailAddress>"
```

instead of just "emailAddress" for the recipient's address but there's no way to push this syntax through Accounts.createUser() and in any event Email.send() works without that complication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is stupid: it merely turned out to be a straggling > character on Accounts.emailTemplates.from. Had to debug Meteor's email.js with node inspector to ultimately find it but it's now working.