# I can send emails, but not replies with smtplib and GMail

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I'm making a program that replies automatically to emails on my GMail account. I can send mails just fine, but I can't seem to reply to them. I'm using `smtplib`.

This is the code I use for sending plain mails (suppose that `foobar@gmail.com` is my personal email):

```
# params contains the header data of the original email.
print smtpserver.sendmail(
    "Name Surname <foobar@gmail.com>",
    str(params["From"]),
    msg
)
```

This is what I use to send replies:

```
print smtpserver.sendmail(
    "Giul Mus <giul.mus@gmail.com>",
    str(params["From"]),
    msg,
    {
        "In-Reply-To": params["Message-ID"],
        "Message-ID": email.utils.make_msgid(),
        "References": params["Message-ID"],
        "Subject": "Re: " + params["Subject"]
    }
)
```

The former works correctly, and I can see the mail it sent in my mailbox; however, the latter fails with this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imap.py", line 65, in <module>
    imapprocess(imapdata[0].split(" "))
  File "imap.py", line 55, in imapprocess
    raise e
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (555, '5.5.2 Syntax error. o2sm22774327wjo.3 - gsmtp', 'Name Surname <foobar@gmail.com>')
```

Why does this happen? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321346/555-5-5-2-syntax-error-gmails-smtp), question, but it wasn't of any help (I tried sending it from `"Foo Bar <foobar@gmail.com>"`, `"<foobar@gmail.com>"`, or to `"<hardcoded-address@gmail.com>"`, but none of these worked).

Comment: According to [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail), the fourth argument is "mail_options", or "a list of ESMTP options (such as 8bitmime) to be used in MAIL FROM commands." This is not what you are passing in.

Comment: @Robᵩ What should I pass for `mail_options` instead, and where should I pass my options? Apologies, I don't have experience with SMTP and mail protocols.

Comment: You probably shouldn't pass anything in mail_options. A list of possible values is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP#Extensions, but you probably don't need any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are not to be passed as an argument, but for whatever reason they actually belong in the message. Here is an example:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart("mixed")
body = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
body.attach(MIMEText(text, "plain"))
body.attach(MIMEText("<html>" + text + "</html>", "html"))
msg.attach(body)
msg["In-Reply-To"] = params["Message-ID"]
msg["Message-ID"] = email.utils.make_msgid()
msg["References"] = params["Message-ID"]
msg["Subject"] = "Re: " + params["Subject"]
destination = msg["To"] = params["Reply-To"] or params["From"]
smtpserver.sendmail(
    "<foobar@gmail.com>",
    destination,
    msg.as_string()
)
```