# C# OAuth2 SMTPclient.Authenticate() exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, oauth-2.0, smtp, mailkit

I added Service Account to my email@gmail.com, activated OAuth2 for it and downloaded the key. Then I followed the steps described in this (life saving) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195508/smtp-and-oauth-2) with the only difference that I instantiated "credential" from Json file (loading p12 would always give me "Invalid network password"). With this I can successfully get Access Token, here is the line which does it:

```
Task<bool> result = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```

Then I instantiate SmtpClient from MailKit and try to connect and authenticate:

```
client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("email@gmail.com", credential.Token.AccessToken);
client.Authenticate(oauth2);
```

The last line generates exception that reads ***555: 5.5.2 Syntax error, goodbye. l13sm3080685qtv.82 - gsmtp***. The part that ends with .82 changes with each subsequent call. As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321346/555-5-5-2-syntax-error-gmails-smtp), I tried different variants for "email@gmail.com" (i.e. <email@gmail.com>). I also tried to use the Service Account email instead (the one similar to this: appName@serviceName.iam.gserviceaccount.com) but to no avail. I mad sure I am using latest versions of MailKit, MimeKit and Google.Api* and searched extensively but found nothing that could provide a solution.

Interestingly, without any change to the code I started experiencing different exception. It now comes partially base64 ecoded and reads this (after decoding):
**334: {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}**

In the meantime I tried 2 other implementations that claim they got it right. None works - they all succeed with getting access token but break on "authenticate". All of that blows once's mind and makes the effort even more hopeless. One wonders if there is any C# code that is truly successful in sending gmail message using OAuth2... Any hint or other form of help would be greatly appreciated.

---

The method pointed by jstedfast below works well but I'd like to follow up with few issues. Too much for standard comment, so I added it here:

When the flow is executed for the  first time, it opens popup browser window and user must login/approve the application/service to access gmail account. It loooks like access key must be stored on the hard drive. If I removed "DataStore" from GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow constructor, the browser seems to popup each time when executing the code. The app I have to fix normally runs without any user interaction. Is there a way to avoid browser popup by enabling/disabling something in gmail account or service/app defined in developer's console? If standard gmail account cannot be used this way, perhaps email that is a part of GSuite domain can? The customer who owns the application uses Google GSuite and they have their domain with emails and documents. I think that now I understand jstedfast's remark on client-to-server vs server-to-server.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these directions to get this working: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/GMailOAuth2.md

If you are loading a .p12, then you are doing it wrong. That method is for service-to-service, not client-to-service. The instructions I provided above is for client-to-service.

Comment: Thank you so much jstedfast - the method works like a charm ! Jut fyi: I am not useing p12 as I quickly learned I cannot overcome "invalid network password" when constructing X509 class. Anyway, I still need some help - added questions in the main post. Would you be able to point at a solution as reliable as the first one ? I value your thoughts/recommendations !

Comment: The problem with OAuth2 is that it requires periodic user-interaction, typically in the form of presenting the user with a web-browser UI and having them authenticate with GMail. There's not really a good way around it that I am aware of. That said, you can tell the user to go into their GMail settings and toggle "Enable less-secure apps" and then you can use a regular username & password combo rather than OAuth2.

Comment: Thanks a lot jstedfast, you surely known the subject. The fun-factor here is that I've been tasked with making the app working with GMail/GSuite accounts in a way that they do not have to be switched to "less secure" mode. I was hoping that with all those "secrets", "certificates" "IDs" and services/accounts/APIs a developer can get some break. Well does not look like that's the case...