# How authenticate an SMTP connection using oauth for sending mail in c#?

Tags: c#, email, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, smtp

How authenticate an SMTP connection using oauth2 for sending mail in c#?

I generated the token with MSal library

I have these parameter

clientId,
clientSecret,
authority :https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId
and
scopes: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

I don't know if these are the right settings to be able to send emails (office 365) via SMTP with oauth2.  The application is registered on Azure Ad (Microsoft entry ID).  On this one I have active Microsoft graph and Microsoft exchange online

If it is not possible there is a work around
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wouldn't use the SMTP protocol then, it would be a REST call to the Graph API.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63963708/c-sharp-oauth2-smtpclient-authenticate-exceptions

Comment: @gunr2171 : There is a frontend which is a connection between a client and a Azure Server.  Then there is an SMTP connection to a email server in the backend

Comment: This may als help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an **Azure AD application** and grant office 365 Exchange Online API permissions:

[image]

Make use of **client credential flow** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://outlook.office.com/.default
```

[image]

Use the below code to authenticate an SMTP connection using oauth for sending mail:

```cs
var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create (clientId)
    .WithAuthority ($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
    .WithCertificate (certificate) // or .WithClientSecret (clientSecret)
    .Build ();
 
var scopes = new string[] {
    // For IMAP and POP3, use the following scope
    "https://ps.outlook.com/.default"

    // For SMTP, use the following scope
    // "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
};

var authToken = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient (scopes).ExecuteAsync ();
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (accountEmailAddress, authToken.AccessToken);

using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    await client.ConnectAsync ("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync (oauth2);
    await client.DisconnectAsync (true);
}
```

And add grant access to the user:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "xxx@example.com" -User ServicePrincipalID -AccessRights FullAccess
```

**References:**

[MailKit/ExchangeOAuth2.md at master · jstedfast/MailKit · GitHub](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md) by  jstedfast

[Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)